Camera 2 API Get Maximum Supported resolution same as default camera application
I’m developing a camera application using the Camera2 API on the Google Pixel 8 Pro, which supports a 50MP camera. Although the device has full hardware-level support for the Camera2 API, I’m only able to retrieve a maximum output size of 12MP. I'm aiming to capture images at the full 50MP resolution but haven't been able to achieve this so far. Could you assist in identifying how to access the full 50MP resolution?
Example
Device Name : Pixle 8Pro
Default Camera App:   8165 x 6124 (50MP) maximum Resolution to capture photo
Camera 2 API :  4000 X 3000
Camera2  INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL =1
Please Let me know if you have any query?

Available resolutions for 3rd party apps for Pixel 8(I do not have the pro) are for video 4K(3840x2160) or 4080x3072. for jpeg image capturing - the same. 3rd party apps do not get the full abilities of the hardware. something else: you can force the camera to zoom into 0.6 to force changing the physical camera to the wide one from the logical cameras (mBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_ZOOM_RATIO, ZoomOptical);)
